# Haskell - Use Just or no Just made difference, but I don't know why

Tags: types, haskell, option-type

I've found such code in the book "Real World Haskell", p68

```
data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
            | Empty
              deriving (Show)

nodeAreSame (Node a _ _) (Node b _ _)
            | a == b = Just a
nodeAreSame _ _ = Nothing
```

My question is: What job did the `Just` data constructor do? When I delete it, I will get  error message such like

```
(in ghci)
......
<Main *> nodeAreSame (Node 3 Empty Empty) (Node 3 Empty Empty))  

<interactive>:1:16:  
    No instance for (Num (Maybe a))
......
```

But when I try to compare the type difference between "Just" and "No Just" version:

```
nodeAreSameJust   :: (Eq t) => Tree t -> Tree t -> Maybe t

nodeAreSameNoJust :: (Eq a) => Tree (Maybe a) -> Tree (Maybe a) -> Maybe a
```

So what is the key point here? Does it means when I put a var with type `a` in the node, the function will not output a node with type `a`, so it get an error?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In fact, the absence of `Just` does **not** make it ill-typed.

Here's the deal.  The code

`nodeAreSame (Node a _ _) (Node b _ _)
            | a == b = a
nodeAreSame _ _ = Nothing`

**is** well-typed provided that `a` and `b` are of type `Maybe t` for some `t`, since that's the type of `Nothing`.  Thus the type system makes this inference.

Now, when you have a numeric literal like `3`, it is inferred to be of type `Num s => s` until you actually commit it to a particular data type (like `Int` or `Double`).

So when it puts these two facts together, it presumes the following:

`Num (Maybe t) => 3 :: Maybe t`.

As there is no instance for `Num (Maybe t)`, it complains at that point, before getting a chance to complain that `3 :: Maybe t` makes no sense.

Answer (score 3):

What else would you expect to return, simply `a`?  That won't work, because `a` and `Nothing` aren't the same type.  All definitions of a function have to return the same type.  `Nothing` and `Just a` match because they're both of type `Maybe a`.

Answer (score 2):

In the no Just version, it requires the item in the tree to be type Maybe a.

I'm not entirely sure the reason the error is for instance of Num (Maybe a). I think the error is more enlightening if you use a string instead of the 3.

```
*Main> nodeAreSameNoJust (Node "arst" Empty Empty) (Node "arst" Empty Empty)
<interactive>:1:24:

Couldn't match expected type `Maybe a'
       against inferred type `[Char]'
In the first argument of `Node', namely `"arst"'
In the first argument of `nodeAreSameNoJust', namely
    `(Node "arst" Empty Empty)'
In the expression:
    nodeAreSameNoJust
      (Node "arst" Empty Empty) (Node "arst" Empty Empty)
```

Here it's more clear that it's expecting something of type Maybe a. In both cases, the second case of the function is Nothing, so the result type is inferred to be Maybe a. By including the Just, the value you use in the tree are then put into a maybe type. Without this, it expects the resulting a to be the same type as Nothing, since each part of the function needs to be the same type.